Run Unit Test and application within the same transaction when using Quarkus and Panache
I am building a Quarkus application with a REST-Resource that will return the result of a database query. The Resource will take an ID as a param and query the database with it. The result is returned as a response to the REST caller.
I now want to write a unit test that does the following:

set up the database by inserting some elements (fruits, modelled as Fruit entities with Panache)
perform the REST call using RestAssured
evaluate the response

I tried doing it by adding @TestTransaction to my test. This will cause the entities to be persisted in the DB and returned when calling Fruit.findAll().list() within the test. However, when calling Fruit.findAll().list() from within the Resource, the list is empty. I think it has to do with transactions. It works if I call Transaction transaction = Panache.getSession().beginTransaction() before inserting the entitites and then transaction.commit() afterwards, but I don't think that's how Quarkus tests are supposed to work, since there is a @TestTransaction mentioned in https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing.
I'm new to Quarkus. What's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?
I set up the unit test as follows:
    @Test
    @TestTransaction
    void findFruitById_shouldReturnFruit() {
        Fruit apple = createFruit("Apple", "keeps the doctor away");
        Fruit banana = createFruit("Banana", "best with ice cream");
        Fruit kiwi = createFruit("Kiwi", "mean green vitamin machine");
        Fruit.persist(List.of(apple, banana, kiwi));

        List<Fruit> list = Fruit.findAll().list(); // list contains fruits

        given()
            .when().get("/fruit/1")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("$.id", equalTo(apple.id))
            .body("$.name", equalTo(apple.name))
            .body("$.description", equalTo(apple.description))
        ;
    }

    private Fruit createFruit(String name, String description) {
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.name = name;
        fruit.description = description;
        return fruit;
    }

The Resource code is as follows:
@Path("/fruit/{id}")
@ApplicationScoped
public class FruitResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public FruitDto getFruitById(String id) {
        List<Fruit> list = Fruit.findAll().list(); // list is empty
        (...) // some mapping from Fruit to DTO done here
    }
}

I expected the call to Fruit.findAll().list() to return all entities in the Resource (just like it does in the test), but the list is empty.
